# How to Auto-Scroll to Top

Tags: python

Good evening!

I would like some help, I would like that after it is done printing. It will scroll to the top automatically so they can manually read/scroll.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import ctypes
import colorama
from colorama import Style, Fore, Back, init
from rich.console import Console
import shutil
import curses
import sys
import shutil


# Title page
columns = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns

print("Authorized King James Bible".center(columns))
print("Thy word is a lamp unto my feet, and a light unto my path.".center(columns))
print("- Psalms 119:105".center(columns))

# Genesis title and chapter 1
print("\n" + Fore.CYAN + "THE FIRST BOOK OF MOSES CALLED GENESIS" + Fore.RESET + "\n")
print(Fore.GREEN + "Chapter 1" + Fore.RESET + "\n")   

# Genesis chapter 1 verses
print("1:1 ¶ IN the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.")
print("1:2 And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the waters.")
...


# Pause the script
input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

Thanks,

Shawn

PS: Wish it to work on Terminal/Cmd and plus on any terminal.

I tried the suggestions Bing gave me but it didn't work.

Comment: Please format your code. Also, you don't need to include the entirety of Genesis 1 in your post - you can use an ellipsis `...` and cut out most of the text. If I wanted to read the Bible, I would grab a Bible, not visit Stack Overflow.

Comment: Most terminals don't provide a simple pythonic API to scroll around in the GUI. Consider using a program like `less` which controls what text is on the screen rather than where your scrollbar is.

Comment: I see, how do I use the less function?

Comment: I was able to get this to work on cmd to go to the top but terminal did not work.import os
import time
import pyautogui

# Detect the environment
environment = os.getenv('WT_SESSION')

# Use the hotkey for Windows Terminal
if environment is not None:
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "shift", "home")
else:
    # Use the hotkey for CMD
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "home")

# Pause the script
input("Press Enter to continue...")

Comment: You should add your comment as an edit to your answer so it looks more nicely formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
import argparse
import time
import sys
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Key

# Create an argument parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--env", help="Specify the environment (terminal or cmd)", choices=['terminal', 'cmd'])

# Parse the arguments
args = parser.parse_args()

# Create a keyboard controller
keyboard = Controller()

# Use the hotkey for Windows Terminal
if args.env == 'terminal' or sys.stdout.isatty():
    print("This is Windows Terminal")
    with keyboard.pressed(Key.ctrl, Key.shift):
        keyboard.press(Key.home)
        keyboard.release(Key.home)
else:
    print("This is CMD")
    # Use the hotkey for CMD
    with keyboard.pressed(Key.ctrl):
        keyboard.press(Key.home)
        keyboard.release(Key.home)

# Pause the script
time.sleep(2)

# Pause the script
input("Press Enter to continue...")
```